# Templated operation on type-erased type

Tags: c++, type-erasure, c++-templates

I have a template class val -

```
template <typename T>
class val;
```

This has the `*` operator overloaded for any pair of types `T, T2`. Basically a member -

```
template <typename T2>
void operator * (const val<T2>&);
```

Now I have another class `val_holder` that uses type erasure to hold `val` -

```
class val_holder;

template <typename T>
class val_holder_impl: public val_holder {
    val<T> m_val;
};
```

Finally in a separate class I have a template function that `foo<T>` that defines a `val<T> x` and receives as argument a `val_holder* y`.

I need to be able to invoke the `*` operator on `x` and the `m_val` inside the `y`.

I cannot use `dynamic_cast` because the template argument for y's precise type isn't known.

The other solution I tried is to have a virtual function in `val_holder` implemented by `val_holder_impl<T>` that invokes the `*` operator. But passing `x` would require the argument of the virtual function to be templated.

Any suggestions on how to get around this pattern?

Comment: I don’t see a way to do this in general. It seems like you’d want double-dispatch like the visitor pattern provides, but type erasure is all about making the compiler create new concrete types on first use where it must satisfy some Concept. You can’t have that concept be that it can be multiplied by every other type since not every type can be multiplied. If you can constrain one type there may be a way.

Comment: @Ben my conclusion was that this wouldn't be possible either, just because it is potentially possible for the erased types to simply appear in different translation units and it is literally impossible to have the two types together. But I wanted confirmation from someone else. Thanks